# How to read strings from file with sscanf or fscanf?

Tags: string, matlab, text, scanf

So, of course, I'm having a little trouble right now. I'm trying to read a text file that goes something like this in a columnar order. What I would like to do is store the number, character and string columns seperately in arrays.

```
[Numbers] [Characters] [Strings]
```

Now, while I have figured out how to read the number and character columns into their own arrays, I cannot seem to do so with the string column. At least, not with `fscanf` or `sscanf`, which are the commands I want to use.

How can you read a file organized as such using `fscanf` or `sscanf`? (I know about textscan, I want to know if this is possible with fscanf or sscanf).

Okay let me add a little code here. So while I was researching this I tried out the following:

```
fid = fopen('Data.txt', 'w+'); 
i = 1;
while ~feof(fid)
     line = fgets(fid);
     M(i) = sscanf(line, '%d, %c, %s', [3,inf];
     i = i+1; 
end
```

This runs, but M ends up coming out only as a row vector consisting of the first column of numbers in the data file. It just completely ignores the existence of chars and strings.

Now, to get a better understanding of the sscanf function I tried the following

```
fid = fopen('Data.txt', 'w+'); 
    i = 1;
    while ~feof(fid)
         line = fgets(fid);
         M(i) = sscanf(line, '%d, %d, %d', [3,inf];
         i = i+1; 
    end
```

For a sample set of data consisting of just columns of numbers. This, incidentally, does exactly the same thing as previously; it just reads the first number column of the data and quits. So, I don't even know how to use sscanf, feof, or fgets properly, basically. So I could also use some help here as well.

And I know trying to read just columns of numbers is trivial with fscanf, but I'm trying to understand sscanf and fgets here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for would rather be [textscan](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)

It will allow you to read the whole file at once and to specify the format of each column you are reading.

In your case, it should be something like :

```
fileID = fopen('myfile.txt');
C = textscan(fileID, '%f %c %s');
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

As we don't know exactly the format of your text file, you'll probably have to tweak the Format string.

You will get a cell array with the content of the file parsed according to the format specification.

Matlab's documentation explain in details the possibilities, [the format specification](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec), and comes with good examples.

Comment: Right, I know about textscan. Maybe I'll look into it, but I am reluctant because the command only exists, to my knowledge, in matlab, which may not be the only thing I want to do this with. 

I will look into that, but, again, I want to know if this is doable with fscanf or sscanf.

And, I mean, what I said really is the format of the textfile. Just  long (thousand or so values) columns of numbers, characters, and strings. 

In a lot of ways I'm just curious here to see how to do this with fscanf and sscanf. Maybe it's dumb but...I'd like to know.

Comment: Well I have to admit textscan works flawlessly, which, honestly, really irritates me. I just, really, really want to know how to use sscanf and/or fscanf to do this. It has to be possible, and I really don't care how much of a pain it is.